# Transferring files from AWS lambda tmp folder to sftp server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a AWS lambda function that takes some files from an S3 bucket, zips them and transfers the zipped file to a sftp server. When I look in the server, I see that the tmp folder has been carries over with the files and a tmp folder gets created inside the zip file. When I open the zip file, there is a tmp folder and inside that folder are the files that I had zipped. I have scoured the internet and AWS trying to figure out how to change the directory in AWS Lambda when I am retrieving the files to be zipped, but have not had any luck. I don't want to have a tmp folder in my zip file. When I unzip the zip file, I just want to see the files that I had selected to be zipped without any folders.  Does anyone know how to do this? I am programming in Java.

My code is below.

```
    private DownloadFile(){
          File localFile = new File(fileName);
          //pull data and audit files from s3 bucket
          s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("pie-dd-demo/daniel20", fileName), localFile);
          zipOS = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

         //send files to be zipped
         writeToZipFile(fileName, zipOS);
     }




    public static void writeToZipFile(String path, ZipOutputStream zipStream)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File aFile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(aFile);
        ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(path);
        try {
            zipStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                zipStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
                System.out.println(path + "write to zipfile complete");
          }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        // Output expected FileNotFoundExceptions.

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // Output unexpected Exceptions.

    }
    zipStream.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
  }
```

Comment: Is your file in the zip directly in the `tmp` folder or in `tmp/pie-dd-demo`? If it's the latter, then we have to look into how ZipEntries are built. You would always have folders otherwise.

Comment: No, the `pie-dd-demo` is not in my tmp folder. That is the file path in my s3 bucket.  After I pull the file and zip it, it gets stored in AWS lambda's tmp folder in between the function calls. This is where I have the issue. I have function that takes the file from the Aws Lambda tmp file and transfers it to a remote server.  When it transfers it takes the tmp folder (full file path) with it. So in the server a tmp folder gets created that holds the zip file `tmp/zipFileName`. I just want to have the zip file transfers and not the folder with it.

Comment: @jarmod I could not get the `new ZipEntry(path.basename(pathname))` to work. When I write the method for basename and use `path.substring() `to define the basename, I get a type conflict as path is of type File and substring is a String function. I also tried `FilenameUtils.getBaseName(path)`. This removed the tmp folder but it also changed the file to a unix excitable.

Comment: @jarmod - That worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating a zip entry using `new ZipEntry(path)` and that means that the resulting zip file will contain the full path as the name of the zip entry.

You can retrieve the actual filename from a full path/file in Java as follows:

```
File f = new File("/tmp/folder/cat.png");
String fname = f.getName();
```

You can then use `fname` to create the zip entry by calling `new ZipEntry(fname)`.